# How does $\sin(x-2\pi) = \sin(x)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How does $\sin(x-2\pi) = \sin(x)$? Is it so that you can split $\sin(x-2\pi)$ into $\sin(x) - \sin(2\pi)$ and that equals $\sin(x) - 0 = \sin(x)$? Please help. Thank you

Comment: No, what you wrote is a lucky coincidence.

Answer (score 6):

Sine is a periodic function with period 2$\pi$.  Perhaps the easiest way to see this is to use the formula $\sin(a+b) = \sin(a)\cos(b) + \cos(a)\sin(b)$

Answer (score 3):

The Sine function has a period of $2\pi$. The period relates to how often the graph goes a full repetition around the unit circle. It is how long it takes sine to return to the same place. Since it starts at $0$, returning to the same place will yield $0$ as well. Thus $\sin 2\pi =0 .$
Expounding on Euler's answer,

$$\sin (x - 2\pi) = \sin x \cos2\pi + \cos x \sin2\pi = \sin x (1) + \cos x (0) = \sin x$$

See more [here.](http://www.mathwarehouse.com/trigonometry/period-sine-cosine/how-equation-effects-graph.php)